# Counting tranversals in an intersecting family with bounded number of connected components

Tags: combinatorics, convex-analysis, connectedness

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{F}$ be a finite family of subsets of $X$. We call a set $T\subseteq X$ a tranversal set for $\mathcal{F}$ if it intersects every set in $\mathcal{F}$.

Suppose that $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is a finite family of intervals such that any two intersect. Then it is easy to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ admits a transversal set with only one element, namely $\cap\mathcal{F}\neq \emptyset$.

> Suppose that every set in $\mathcal{F}$ is union of at most $n$ points and intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, and again that every two sets in $\mathcal{F}$ intersect. Is there a simple combinatorial argument to show whether $\mathcal{F}$ admits a finite transversal set of a certain cardinality?

My guess here being that one such family might always admit a transversal set of cardinality $n$.

Comment: 1). "an intervals" --> "and intervals". 2). is it "[at most $n$ points] and intervals" or "at most $n$ [points and intervals]"?

Comment: @mathworker21 1)Sure 2) $n$ [points and intervals]

Answer (score 2):

There is the following counterexample to your guess. Given a number $n$ let $\mathcal F$ be a family of all unions of at most $n$ closed intervals with endpoints of the from $p/q$ where $p\le q\le 4n(2n-1)$ be non-negative integers (and $q>0$) and of total length $1/2$. Connectedness of $[0,1]$ easily implies that each two members of $\mathcal F$ intersects. On the other hand, let $T$ be any $2n-2$-point subset of a segment $[0,1]$. Then $T$ splits $[0,1]$ into at most $2n-1$ open intervals, so the total length of $n$ longest of them is al least $\tfrac{n}{2n-1}$. It is easy to show that the union of these intervals contains a member of $\mathcal F$  disjoint from $T$.

Comment: I don't get it. You found a bad $T$. How does this show there is no good $T$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I showed that there is no good $T$ of size $2n-2$.

Comment: I'm assuming $I=[0,1]$ in your reply?

Comment: @Anguepa Thanks. Corrected.